# Conditional Expectation Brownian Motion

Tags: expected-value, brownian-motion

So this is an exam question I had recently and I honestly had no idea on how to solve it.

Let W(t) be a Brownian Motion stochastic process at time t with drift p and variance v^2

Let s exist such that t1 < s < t2.

1. Find E[W(s)| W(t1) = a, W(t2) = b]
2. Find Var[W(s)| W(t1) = a, W(t2) = b]

Comment: Hint: The random vector $(W(t_1), W(s), W(t_2))$ is multivariate normal with some mean vector and covariance matrix that you can compute without much difficulty. Then knowing that, you can use the [well-known properties of conditional distributions of multivariate normal random vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions)